# Generating individual page for image only in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website where I generally post technology-based article and tutorial. Everything is going fine. But recently I noticed some links of my website in my google search console's "Valid but not Included in Sitemap" section that when I post an article with one or a few images then, for every individual image, Wordpress is generating individual pages with a link automatically.

For example, a post link from my Website, https://www.progracoding.com/wps-file-extension/

In that post, I used an image, but for that image, I am getting another link like this: https://www.progracoding.com/gif-file-extension/wps-file-extension/

Is this effect on SEO ranking? If yes, How can I prevent these auto-generated pages?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several Options:

1. Yoast, if you use it, allows disabling this at the Search
   Appearance -> Media tab.
2. There are plugins like "Attachment Pages
   Redirect" which disable it.
3. You can add/edit the according
   template file (image.php) to redirect to the parent post or
   somewhere else:

```
<?php wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->post_parent)); ?>
```

4. Instead of disabling the image pages, you could also exclude them from your sitemap, block them via robots.txt or whatever, which might be more appropriate.